# How to stop a setTimeout for a decided time

Tags: javascript, time, set, settimeout, cleartimeout

```
var time = 1000;
var point = 0;
function interval() { timeout = setTimeout(increment, time);}
function increment(){point += 1;document.getElementById("pul").value = point;interval();}
time2 = 3000;
function fermafatica() {setInterval(ferma, time2);}
function ferma(){clearTimeout(timeout)}
```

i need to stop the interval() function or the setTimeout in interval() for only 1000ms and then to keep it working

Comment: What do you mean by "undo the clearTimeout"? Prevent it from running? You need to show how you are using `x`, `y` and `z`.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. What do you mean undo the cleartimeout, do you mean run the clearTimeout?

Comment: Where are you storing timeout (I know it is technically global but thats just very bad). Unclear what you are asking, as the clearTimeout is _not on a timeout_ so if you want to run function z in a timeout use... setTimeout.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please see if this fixes your problem.

Comment: is not what i'm searching but may have the solution...down there

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    z();
    // Do anything else here
}, 1000);
```

The `setTimeout` function, runs the given function after a set amount of time. This will call the `z()` function, which clears your timeout, after the supplied time of `1000`ms.

EDIT: Everything: See below

```
var time = 1000;
var point = 0;
function interval() { timeout = setTimeout(increment, time);}
function increment(){point += 1;document.getElementById("pul").value = point;interval();}
time2 = 3000;
function fermafatica() {setInterval(ferma, time2);}
function ferma(){clearTimeout(timeout)}
```

Change `function fermafatica() {setInterval(ferma, time);}`

to `function fermafatica() {setTimeout(ferma, time);}`

Comment: Your full code is different to your shortened code. You have `setInterval(ferma` which is not the same as your `setInterval(x` in your first example. I still have no idea what you mean by `is n increasing value code`. What is `n`?

Comment: Yes, the name changed, but the actual function it was calling was not consistent as per your example. E.g. In your real example you were calling the equivalent of `setInterval(z`

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about how to clear a timeout after X seconds? I would consider just having a static variable (lets just call it X) count up within the repeating function, and if the function repeats every 10ms, and you want it to run for 1000ms, then when x==100, clear the timeout.

Comment: You have the code there, use the clearTimeout function.

Comment: you don't understand...
i need to stop the clearTimeout after 1000ms...

Comment: I think I see. Why don't you have a boolean that, if true, prevents the loop function from running. Something like if(bool==true){ //do the normal stuff} else{bool=true} and then set the bool equal to false when you want it to not run for 1000 ms. This will make it skip a timeout cycle, which seems to be what you want

Comment: tried.... it seems thath if I set
Bool=true
and i set function ferma(){clearTimeout(timeout); Bool=false}
the code read it like it is true....

Answer (score 0):

ok.... i "avoid" the problem.... i need to stop the setTimeout for 1000ms and then let it works normally... i tried so... instead of pausing the setTimeout I put another time var.

```
 var time = 1000;
    var timecache = 1000;
    fatica = 3000;
    sudore = 3000;
    function interval() { timeout = setTimeout(increment, time);} //here setTimeout uses var time//
    function increment(){console.log(time);point += 1;document.getElementById("pul").value = point;interval();}
    function fermafatica() {time = timecache;setInterval(ferma, fatica);} //here the function equals time to timecache so vas time is always 1000ms//
    function ferma(){time = 10000; setTimeout(fermafatica, sudore);} // then here I transformed the time in 10000 so the first function will take 10000 instead of 1000 in setTimeout//
//plus i put a setTimeout to recall function fermafatica() that reset the time to 1000//
```

this i what i want... I avoid the problem and found another way to do that... but it works...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/th4p68h3/1/
if you want full code and html 
(is a stupid game... in preprepreprealpha... try it to understand...)